# Solid Java unit test automation? (JUnit/Hamcrest/...)

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

### Intent

I am looking for the following:

- A solid unit testing methodology

  1. What am I missing from my approach?
  2. **What am I doing wrong**?
  3. *What am I doing which is unnecessary?*
- A way to get as much as possible done automatically

### Current environment

- **[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/)** as IDE
- **[JUnit](http://www.junit.org/)** as a testing framework, integrated into Eclipse
- **[Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/)** as a "matchers" library, for better assertion readability
- **[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)** for precondition validation

### Current approach

#### Structure

- One test class per class to test
- Method testing grouped in static nested classes
- Test method naming to specify behaviour tested + expected result
- Expected exceptions specified by Java **[Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html)**, not in method name

#### Methodology

- Watch out for `null` values
- Watch out for empty **[List<E>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)**
- Watch out for empty **[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)**
- Watch out for empty arrays
- Watch out for object state invariants altered by code (post-conditions)
- Methods accept documented parameter types
- Boundary checks (e.g. **[Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)**, etc...)
- Documenting immutability through specific types (e.g. **Google Guava [ImmutableList<E>](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)**)
- *... is there a list for this? Examples of nice-to-have testing lists:*

  - Things to check in database projects (e.g. CRUD, connectivity, logging, ...)
  - Things to check in multithreaded code
  - Things to check for EJBs
  - ... ?

### Sample code

*This is a contrived example to show some techniques.*

---

#### MyPath.java

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
public class MyPath {
  public static final MyPath ROOT = MyPath.ofComponents("ROOT");
  public static final String SEPARATOR = "/";
  public static MyPath ofComponents(String... components) {
    checkNotNull(components);
    checkArgument(components.length > 0);
    checkArgument(!Arrays.asList(components).contains(""));
    return new MyPath(components);
  }
  private final ImmutableList<String> components;
  private MyPath(String[] components) {
    this.components = ImmutableList.copyOf(components);
  }
  public ImmutableList<String> getComponents() {
    return components;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String pathComponent : components) {
      stringBuilder.append("/" + pathComponent);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
}
```

---

#### MyPathTests.java

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsEmptyCollection.empty;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.runners.Enclosed;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class MyPathTests {
  public static class GetComponents {
    @Test
    public void componentsCorrespondToFactoryArguments() {
      String[] components = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };
      MyPath myPath = MyPath.ofComponents(components);
      assertThat(myPath.getComponents(), contains(components));
    }
  }
  public static class OfComponents {
    @Test
    public void acceptsArrayOfComponents() {
      MyPath.ofComponents("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
    }
    @Test
    public void acceptsSingleComponent() {
      MyPath.ofComponents("Test1");
    }
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void emptyStringVarArgsThrows() {
      MyPath.ofComponents(new String[] { });
    }
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void nullStringVarArgsThrows() {
      MyPath.ofComponents((String[]) null);
    }
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void rejectsInterspersedEmptyComponents() {
      MyPath.ofComponents("Test1", "", "Test2");
    }
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void rejectsSingleEmptyComponent() {
      MyPath.ofComponents("");
    }
    @Test
    public void returnsNotNullValue() {
      assertThat(MyPath.ofComponents("Test"), is(notNullValue()));
    }
  }
  public static class Root {
    @Test
    public void hasComponents() {
      assertThat(MyPath.ROOT.getComponents(), is(not(empty())));
    }
    @Test
    public void hasExactlyOneComponent() {
      assertThat(MyPath.ROOT.getComponents(), hasSize(1));
    }
    @Test
    public void hasExactlyOneInboxComponent() {
      assertThat(MyPath.ROOT.getComponents(), contains("ROOT"));
    }
    @Test
    public void isNotNull() {
      assertThat(MyPath.ROOT, is(notNullValue()));
    }
    @Test
    public void toStringIsSlashSeparatedAbsolutePathToInbox() {
      assertThat(MyPath.ROOT.toString(), is(equalTo("/ROOT")));
    }
  }
  public static class ToString {
    @Test
    public void toStringIsSlashSeparatedPathOfComponents() {
      String[] components = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };
      String expectedPath =
          MyPath.SEPARATOR + Joiner.on(MyPath.SEPARATOR).join(components);
      assertThat(MyPath.ofComponents(components).toString(),
          is(equalTo(expectedPath)));
    }
  }
  @Test
  public void testPathCreationFromComponents() {
    String[] pathComponentArguments = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    MyPath myPath = MyPath.ofComponents(pathComponentArguments);
    assertThat(myPath.getComponents(), contains(pathComponentArguments));
  }
}
```

---

### Question, phrased explicitly

- Is there a list of techniques to use to build a unit test? Something much more advanced than my oversimplified list above (e.g. check nulls, check boundaries, check expected exceptions, etc.) perhaps available in a book to buy or a URL to visit?
- Once I have a method that takes a certain type of parameters, can I get any **[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/)** plug-in to generate a stub for my tests for me? Perhaps using a Java **[Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html)** to specify metadata about the method and having the tool materialise the associated checks for me? (e.g. @MustBeLowerCase, @ShouldBeOfSize(n=3), ...)

I find it tedious and robot-like to have to remember all of these "QA tricks" and/or apply them, I find it error-prone to copy and paste and I find it not self-documenting when I code things as I do above. Admittedly, Hamcrest [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/MatcherLibraries) go in the general direction of specialising types of tests (e.g. on **[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)** objects using RegEx, on **[File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)** objects, etc) but obviously do not auto-generate any test stubs and do not reflect on the code and its properties and prepare a harness for me.

Help me make this better, please.

### PS

*Do not tell me that I am just presenting code which is a silly wrapper around the concept of creating a Path from a list of path steps supplied in a static factory method please, this is a totally made-up example but it shows a "few" cases of argument validation... If I included a much longer example, who would really read this post?*

Comment: +1 for well structured question! This is the way all question should be structured.

Comment: Looks like you already have a pretty solid approach. Are there specific things you are not happy with?

Comment: Unhappy about having to do this all by hand. Time/effort/energy levels/accuracy loss after N repetitions/morale... at my age I only have so many hours of _sharp mind_. I can't bear to waste them on repetitive tasks, can you? `:(`. Plus, all the tools I mention are open-source so there is knowledge sharing aplenty in effect, could this extend to creating unit tests? Think `FindBugs`, somebody put a list of bug checks at my fingertips... perhaps there is something similar for setting up unit test? Sounds reasonable?

Comment: Do you consider this test to be complete or just an example?

Comment: An example but if you can add to it, please do. If you can criticise it constructively and make it better, please do.

Comment: @Robottinosino added review to answer. FYI, I will not be logging in for a week so will not be able to clarify if you have questions till then. Didn't want you to think I was not being responsive since you have been so dilegent in creating your questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

1. Consider using [ExpectedException](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) instead of `@Test(expected...`. This is because if for example you expect a `NullPointerException` and your test throws this exception in your setup (before calling the method under test) your test will pass. With `ExpectedException` you put the expect immediately before the call to the method under test so there is no chance of this. Also, `ExpectedException` allows you to test the exception message which is helpful if you have two different `IllegalArgumentExceptions` that might be thrown and you need to check for the correct one.
2. Consider isolating your method under test from the setup and verify, this will ease in test review and maintenance. This is especially true when methods on the class under test are invoked as part of setup which can confuse which is the method under test. I use the following format:

   ```
   public void test() {
      //setup
      ...

      // test (usually only one line of code in this block)
      ...

      //verify
      ...
   }
   ```
3. Books to look at: [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), [JUnit In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182021), [Test Driven Development By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)

   Clean Code has an excellent section on testing
4. Most example I have seen (including what Eclipse autogenerates) have the method under test in the title of the test. This facilitates review and maintenance. For example: `testOfComponents_nullCase`. Your example is the first I have seen that uses the `Enclosed` to group methods by method under test, which is really nice. However, it adds some overhead as `@Before` and `@After` do not get shared between enclosed test classes.
5. I have not started using it, but Guava has a test library: [guava-testlib](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/?name=v12.0-rc1). I have not had a chance to play with it but it seems to have some cool stuff. For example: [NullPointerTest](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/NullPointerTester.java?name=v12.0-rc1) is quote:

> - A test utility that verifies that your methods throw {@link   * NullPointerException} or {@link UnsupportedOperationException} whenever any   * of their parameters are null. To use it, you must first provide valid default   * values for the parameter types used by the class.

Review: I realize the test above was just an example but since a constructive review might be helpful, here you go.

1. In testing `getComponents`, test the empty list case as well. Also, use `IsIterableContainingInOrder`.
2. In testing of `ofComponents`, it seems that it would make sense to call `getComponents` or `toString` to validate that it properly handled the various non-error cases. There should be a test where no argument is passed to `ofComponents`. I see that this is done with `ofComponents( new String[]{})` but why not just do `ofComponents()`? Need a test where `null` is one of the values passed: `ofComponents("blah", null, "blah2")` since this will throw an NPE.
3. In testing `ROOT`, as has been pointed out before, I suggest calling `ROOT.getComponents` once and doing all three verifications on it. Also, `ItIterableContainingInOrder` does all three of not empty, size and contains. The `is` in the tests is extraineous (although it is linguistic) and I feel is not worth having (IMHO).
4. In testing `toString`, I feel it is very helpful to isolate the method under test. I would have written `toStringIsSlashSeparatedPathOfComponents` as follows. Notice that I do not use the constant from the class under test. This is because IMHO, ANY functional change to the class under test should cause the test to fail.

   ```
   @Test     
   public void toStringIsSlashSeparatedPathOfComponents() {       
      //setup 
      String[] components = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };       
      String expectedPath =  "/" + Joiner.on("/").join(components);   
      MyPath path = MyPath.ofComponents(components)

      // test
      String value = path.toStrign();

      // verify
      assertThat(value, equalTo(expectedPath));   
   }
   ```
5. `Enclosed` will not run any unit test that is not in an inner class. Therefore `testPathCreationFromComponents` would not be run.

Finally, use Test Driven Development. This will ensure that your tests are passing for the right reason and will fail as expected.

Comment: +1 That's very cool. I didn't know about JUnit [TestRules](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html)

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the input. Please edit your message and include a small code snippet?

Comment: still reviewing the post, will continue to add comments

Comment: need example of which part, 1 or 2?

Comment: @JohnB Before and After don't get shared, but you can always use an ExternalResource TestRule: https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.java

Answer (score 3):

I see you put a lot of effort to really test your classes. Good! :)

My comments/questions would be:

- what about mocking? you do not mention any tool for this
- it seems to me that you care a lot about the nitty-gritty details (I do not say they are not important!), while neglecting the business purpose of tested class. I guess it comes from the fact you code code-first (do you?). What I would suggest is more TDD/BDD approach and focus on business responsibilities of the tested class.
- not sure what this gives you: "Method testing grouped in static nested classes"?
- regarding auto-generation of test stubs etc. Simply put: don't. You will end up testing implementation instead of behaviour.

Comment: +1 for auto-generation testing implementation instead of expected behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is my view on your questions:

### Is there a list of techniques to use to build a unit test?

Short answer, no. Your problem is that to generate a test for a method, you need to analyse what it does and put a test in for each possible value in each place. There are/were test generators, but IIRC, they didn't generate maintainable code (see [Resources for Test Driven Development](http://www.junit.org/taxonomy/term/7)).

You've already got a fairly good list of things to check, to which I would add:

- Make sure all paths through your methods are covered.
- Make sure all important functionality is covered by more than one test, I use Parameterized a lot for this.

One thing I find really useful to do is to ask what *should* this method be doing, as opposed to what *does* this method do. This way, you write the tests with a more open mind.

Another thing I find useful is to cut down on the boilerplate associated with the tests, so I can read the tests more easily. The easier it is to add tests, the better. I find Parameterized very good for this. For me, readability of tests is key.

So, taking your example above, if we drop the requirement 'test only one thing in a method' we get

```
public static class Root {
  @Test
  public void testROOT() {
    assertThat("hasComponents", MyPath.ROOT.getComponents(), is(not(empty())));
    assertThat("hasExactlyOneComponent", MyPath.ROOT.getComponents(), hasSize(1));
    assertThat("hasExactlyOneInboxComponent", MyPath.ROOT.getComponents(), contains("ROOT"));
    assertThat("isNotNull", MyPath.ROOT, is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat("toStringIsSlashSeparatedAbsolutePathToInbox", MyPath.ROOT.toString(), is(equalTo("/ROOT")));
  }
}
```

I've done two things, I've added the description into the assert, and I've merged all of the tests into one. Now, we can read the test and see that we've actually got duplicate tests. We probably don't need to test `is(not(empty())` && `is(notNullValue())`, etc. This violates the one assert per method rule, but I think it's justified because you've removed lots of boilerplate without cutting down on coverage.

### Can I perform checks automatically?

Yes. But I wouldn't use annotations to do it. Let's say we have a method like:

```
public boolean validate(Foobar foobar) {
  return !foobar.getBar().length > 40;
}
```

So I have a test method which says something like:

```
private Foobar getFoobar(int length) {
  Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
  foobar.setBar(StringUtils.rightPad("", length, "x")); // make string of length characters
  return foobar;
}

@Test
public void testFoobar() {
  assertEquals(true, getFoobar(39));
  assertEquals(true, getFoobar(40));
  assertEquals(false, getFoobar(41));
}
```

The above method is easy enough to factor out depending upon the length, into a Parameterized test of course. Moral of the story, you can factorize your tests just as you can with non-test code.

So to answer your question, in my experience, I've come to the conclusion that you can do a lot to help with all of the combinations by cutting down on boilerplate within your tests, by using a judicious combination of Parameterized and factorization of your tests. As a final example, this is how I would implement your test with Parameterized:

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
  public static class OfComponents {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection data() {
          return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
          { new String[] {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"}, null },
          { new String[] {"Test1"}, null },
          { null, NullPointerException.class },
          { new String[] {"Test1", "", "Test2"}, IllegalArgumentException },
        });
    }

```
private String[] components;

@Rule
public TestRule expectedExceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

public OfComponents(String[] components, Exception expectedException) {
   this.components = components;
   if (expectedException != null) {
     expectedExceptionRule.expect(expectedException);
   }
}

@Test
public void test() {
  MyPath.ofComponents(components);
}
```

Please note that the above isn't tested and probably doesn't compile. From the above, you can analyse the data as input and add (or at least think about adding) all of the combinations of everything. For instance, you haven't got a test for {"Test1", null, "Test2"} ...

Comment: I disagree with the notion of testing multiple method in one test. First it makes the intention of the test more difficult to understand. Second (and more importantly) since JUnit is fail-fast, the first failure will hide all subsequent. I follow the rule, the one method per test method, invoke the method under test only once per test method, verify as much as makes sense for the single invokation.

Comment: I'm not testing more than one method in the same test method. I'm testing MyPath.ROOT is correct. I'm not saying that it applies to all situations, but in this case I think it's acceptable because it makes the test so much clearer.

Comment: @JohnB Actually, in the case of MyPath.ROOT, even if it were called more than once, which it's not because it's a static variable, you can put the result of MyPath.ROOT into a local variable. You're right that the first failure will hide the second.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will post 2 difference answers.

1. As James Coplien stated unit test is worthless. I disagree with him on this issue, but may be you will find this helpful to consider to unit test less instead of searching for automatic solution.
2. Consider to use Theories with DataPoints. I think this will minimize your problem significantly. Also, using mock can help you.