# TDD/BDD and model validation

Tags: validation, model, tdd, bdd

I keep wondering what is the most common way to handle model validations in BDD/TDD? Do you write a test for every single field in the model, and validate on that? Do you write a single validation test and validate everything inside?

I'd really like to know more, and how everyone is doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513184/solid-java-unit-test-automation-junit-hamcrest), the example in the question is a very good example of how to do validation with TDD... it's quite exhaustive too.